# How to programmatically create/edit an RTF header in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-word, rtf

So, the problem is there I already have the formatted text in RTF format but when I save the file it gets "wrong", the header disappears.

I'm using the **RichTextBox** Class to create the file, where **finalText** is the formatted RTF text, making the code look something like this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox RichTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
string finalText = "{\rtf1\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Calibri;}{\f1 Arial;}{\f2 ..." //Formatted RTF here
RichTextBox.Rtf = finalText;

RichTextBox.SaveFile(_RtfPath_);
```

When I do this the final version of the generated file is almost complete, but the **header** disappears.

Editing the file in *notepad++* I noticed that it removes the header and the information contained in it. After this I decided to manually create an RTF file. I opened the almost complete RTF file in *notepad++*, erased everything and pasted the **finalText**.

When I reopened this file the final version was the way I wanted it.

Is there any way I can save the text as **RTF** without having to use the **RichTextBox** Class to format the output file?

Comment: Have you tried using (File.WriteAllText)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-5.0] which creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file.

Comment: It helped more than half the battle, thanks a lot! Now I can imagine how to finish it.